# How do I use a recursive array iterator to process a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, recursion, iterator, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get something like this working:

```
function posts_formatter (&$posts){
    foreach ($posts as $k => $v){

        if (is_array($v)){

            posts_formatter($v);

        }else{

            switch (strtolower($k)){

                # make email addresses lowercase
                case (strpos($k, 'email') !== FALSE):
                    $posts[$k] = strtolower($v);
                    break;

                # make postcodes uppercase
                case (strpos($k, 'postcode') !== FALSE):
                    $posts[$k] = strtoupper($v);
                    break;

                # capitalize certain things
                case (strpos($k, 'line1') !== FALSE):
                case (strpos($k, 'line2') !== FALSE):
                case (strpos($k, 'line3') !== FALSE):
                case (strpos($k, 'forename') !== FALSE):
                case (strpos($k, 'surname') !== FALSE):
                    $posts[$k] = capitalize($v);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

It will correctly go through the array and format the values but I can't get it to return them. I've played around with removing the `&` from the function declaration and adding a return at the end but it won't do anything.

Additionally, I'm thinking perhaps using a `RecursiveArrayIterator` might be the way to go. However, despite the presence of a book right in front of me with a chapter on SPL Iterators its examples are useless towards being able to achieve what I'm trying to. How would I go about implementing one?

Edit:

```
array (
  'user' => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Mr.',
    'forename' => 'lowercase',
    'surname' => 'name',
    'businessName' => 'some dude',
    'telephone' => '07545464646',
    'postcode' => 'wa1 6nj',
    'line1' => 'blergh road',
    'line2' => 'randomLY cApitaLIzed wOrds',
    'line3' => '',
  ),
  'email' => 'CAPITALIZED@BLERGH.com',
  'address' => 
  array (
    'postcode' => 'ab1 1ba',
    'line1' => 'test road',
    'line2' => 'testville',
    'line3' => 'testshire',
  ),
  'date' => '2010-09-30'
)
```

Comment: care to provide a `var_export` example array?

Comment: Well, the array can be any multidimensional (or basic) array, which is the whole point. All the function needs to do is look for those specific keys, which may or may not exist within the array and format their values. The question is getting it to output them back to the script.

Comment: I am asking because in order to write up an example, I'd like to use your actual data instead of coming up with a dummy array. It's just to make it less tedious to code things up for you.

Comment: Your switch/case construct doesn't work the way you probably intent it to do. What you have is like `if ( strtolower($k) == (strpos($k, 'email')!==FALSE) )`.

Comment: Fair enough! I was thinking you needed it to better understand the problem.

Comment: Booleans should be `true` and `false`, not `TRUE` or `FALSE`. It works, but it's ugly code (not that PHP in general is pretty). Same with `null`.

Comment: @VolkerK It started out as an if statement but I thought it would get messy if I wanted to add new cases. It is currently doing what I intended.

Comment: @Tor Valamo Is that personal preference, convention or something else?

Comment: @Tor Valamo From the PHP manual: `To specify a boolean literal, use the keywords TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.`

Comment: thanks, I whipped up a small array myself in the meantime. Please let me know if the example is not sufficient. I will change it to use your array then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, here is a quick something for you to figure out:

```
$data = array(
    'title'    => 'how to work with iterators',
    'posts' => array(
        array(
        'title'  => 'introduction to iterators',
        'email'  => 'JohnDoe@example.com'
     ), array(
        'title'  => 'extending iterators',
        'email'  => 'JaneDoe@example.com'
     )
));
```

The main idea is to influence how the `Iterator` returns the `current` element. Iterators are stackable, so you should use a `RecursiveArrayIterator` and wrap it into a `RecursiveIteratorIterator`. To achieve custom functionality, you can either subclass the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` (as shown below) or use additional iterators to decorate the `RecursiveIteratorIterator`:

```
class PostFormatter extends RecursiveIteratorIterator
{
    public function current()
    {
        $current = parent::current();
        switch($this->key()) {
            case 'email':
                $current = strtolower($current);
                break;
            case 'title':
                $current = ucwords($current);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return $current;
    }
}
```

Then you simply `foreach` over the iterator

```
$it = new PostFormatter(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));
foreach($it as $key => $post) {
    echo "$key: $post", PHP_EOL;
}
```

and get

```
title: How To Work With Iterators
title: Introduction To Iterators
email: johndoe@example.com
title: Extending Iterators
email: janedoe@example.com
```

---

You can try to get the array back from the with `iterator_to_array` or `iterator_apply` functions. However, to get the values reapplied to the original array structure, you dont need an iterator:

```
array_walk_recursive($data, function(&$val, $key) {
    switch($key) {
        case 'title': $val = ucwords($val); break;
        case 'email': $val = strtolower($val); break;
        default: break;
    }
});
print_r($data);
```

Note: exchange Lambda with Function name when using PHP<5.3

Comment: Thanks for your help Gordon. Just one more quick Q- how do I amend it return the processed array with the original array structure intact?

Comment: @bcmcfc You're welcome. I had to remove the iterator_to_array code because it wouldnt apply the changes to the inner arrays. I am sure you can do it somehow, but right now I cant fiddle with it (time constraints). Sorry.